# How to send order to Binance via google apps script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, binance

I want to connect google apps script to Binance website to post api.

API documentation of Binance:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/

I want to send order by using google apps script but I have no idea how to do that?

Comment: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade

Comment: this is for new order trade codes

Comment: but I do not know how to use in google apps script b using API, public and private API is available.

Comment: Take a look at [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).